# How to setup proxies for requests.get() to work in Pycharm?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, pycharm

I'm trying to use requests function from PyCharm.

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.google.com'
ProxyDict = {"http_proxy":"http://proxy-us.MyCompany.com:911","https_proxy":"http://proxy-us.MyCompany.com:912"}
o = requests.get(url,proxies = ProxyDict)
print(o.status_code)
```

It is giving me

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027CBF508B00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

But when I tried to run following from cmd, it worked.

```
$set http_proxy=http://proxy-us.MyCompany.com:911
$set https_proxy=http://proxy-us.MyCompany.com:912
$ python ip_locator.py
200
```

I tried following:

1. setup system env variable called HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY
2. in Pycharm, Ctrl+Alt+S --> HTTP Proxy -> Automatic proxy configuration URL:http://proxy-us.MyCompany.com:911

But none of my methods have been successful in setting the proxy in PyCharm. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Seems I have found a solution.

**Pycharm -> Run -> Edit Configuration -> Environment Variable**

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;http_proxy=http://proxy-us.MyCompany.com:911;https_proxy=http://proxy-us.MyCompany.com:912
```

Comment: Above solved my problem. Thanks . Earlier I used to pass proxy in my request call, but that was just extra code only for local, above method made the code very clean

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong dictionary keys to `requests.get`.

According to docs, keys should be named `http` and `https`: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

Example from docs:

```
proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

But because proxies also could be configured through environment variables, your second approach is working: you're setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables. And `requests` accept them as proxy configuration.

Comment: Correct. Great catch. Thanks